# Closing Buddhism Stack Exchange Account

Tags: support, status-completed

How do I close my buddhism stack exchange account only without affecting my other account on the stack exchange community?

Comment: http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/158/do-the-moderators-here-have-the-ability-to-delete-buddhism-stackexchange-account

Comment: Can you delete the account? Thanks.

Comment: Scheduled for deletion as per your request.

Comment: Just to give you some of my observations on the way out the door. The site reflects in many ways much of what is problematic in Buddhism. The creation of conceptual complexity instead of simplicity, the adherence to strict set preconceptions instead of flexibility, and intellectualism and book learning instead of direct experience.

Comment: Good points, but this isn't a Buddhist site; it's an expert exchange on Buddhism. After discussion and reading, I think it was my mistake to delete the last few one-line answers, but if they don't actually answer the question, they are better off as comments (I've converted one to a comment [here](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1969/is-zazen-practised-for-its-own-sake-or-as-a-means-to-end-suffering-experts-see)).

Comment: Let me know if there is any way to change your mind; you have 23 hours to cancel the deletion.

Comment: Actually if you read the question I answered previously despite the question header, the question asked was actually how it is possible through Dual practise to attain Non-Duality. My answer was to correctly point to existential non-duality.But that said, I had conjectured I wouldn't be a good fit here, so its been a bit of an experiment on my part to see what would happen. No hard feelings.

Comment: This is not Buddhism zork, this is a crowd of beginners talking about Buddhism online. Direct experience is your frustration with us and the feeling of wrongness -- this is what dukkha is.

Comment: I have to admit, my non-expertise in Zen means I'm not really sure if your answer was an answer or not. It didn't seem like an answer (as per the heading anyway). I'm willing to return it to its position as an answer if you believe it actually answered the question.

Comment: I drifted into the Buddhism stack exchange on an advertised link in my other account,out of curiosity, I didn't go looking for it, had a feeling I probably wouldn't last long, haven't, and I'm content to leave it there, with no bad feelings on my part. Just not a good fit.

Comment: Its really just the way it has to be. On the one hand you correctly want answers offering reasonably objective pointers, on the other hand anyone offering direct insight is only as good as their insight - and how do you start making reasonably objective judgements about the quality of their insight when your experience may be very different to theirs? That could be a recipe for all kinds of rubbish being posted.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the nature of the beast. The stairway to Enlightenment is made of soft concepts (which are basically half-illusions), plus solid practice. All this talk hopefully stimulates behavioral changes in people daily lives. That's when real Buddhism begins.

Comment: @yuttadhammo Can you delete this account? Thanks. –  Rob Mac Hugh

Comment: @RobMacHugh your account is now scheduled for deletion in 24 hours.