# Closing account

Tags: support, status-completed

I've attempted to have my account closed before by posting in meta and asking a moderator to close it and it still seems very much active. Today I received a message in reply to a question I answered. Just wondering what else to do?

Answer (score 1):

I found your delete request [here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202/closing-buddhism-stack-exchange-account). Strangely that post currently belongs to the deleted 'user319' (which is also you!), but this could simply be caused by a caching issue.

Normally, requesting your profile to be deleted once is enough. I think I remember seeing posts on the main site by a deleted user319, so your account probably was deleted. I'm not sure why you received email notifications. That's not something that normally happens, at least not after several hours after deletion. Perhaps one of the mods can find the cause for that.

In any case, since you've reactivated your account to post this meta question, you'll probably have to ask for deletion again.

Comment: Can one of the mods here cancel my account. Thanks.

Comment: Bizarre. I'm not sure what happened, but I'll try it again.

Comment: Deletion is now scheduled. My theory is that your *meta* account was deleted before, but not your main site account. That should be rectified now.